QPE implementation with 4 qubits
I'm trying to implement a circuit for QPE, i start with 4 qubits but the results are incorrect (even for 3 or 5 qubits).
the used unitary gate is : U = UnitaryGate(Operator([[1,0,0,0],[0,1,0,0],[0,0,1,0],[0,0,0,np.exp(pi*2j*(10/16))]]), label="U")
and this my impolementation
size_eig = 4
size_phi = 2
eig = QuantumRegister(size_eig, name="eig")
phi = QuantumRegister(size_phi, name="phi")
ceig = ClassicalRegister(size_eig, name="ceig")
qc = QuantumCircuit(eig,phi,ceig)
qc.x(phi)
qc.h(eig)
qc.append(U.power(1).control(), [eig[3]] + list(phi))
qc.append(U.power(2).control(), [eig[2]] + list(phi)) 
qc.append(U.power(4).control(), [eig[1]] + list(phi)) 
qc.append(U.power(8).control(), [eig[0]] + list(phi)) 
qc.append(QFT(size_eig).inverse(), eig) 
qc.measure(eig,ceig) 
qc.draw() 

for example, for the value 10/16 in the unitary gate, the output is supposed to be a bit string around the value 1010 but i get 1101 with a frequency 512 but i get 0101 (the wanted value but reversed) with a frequency of 237. What is the problem ?


The issue is with the control bits.
You are apply $U^1$ using the most significant bit, and $U^8$ using the least significant bit. This order needs to be reversed.
This is what I get if I replace this block of your code:
qc.append(U.power(1).control(), [eig[3]] + list(phi))
qc.append(U.power(2).control(), [eig[2]] + list(phi))
qc.append(U.power(4).control(), [eig[1]] + list(phi))
qc.append(U.power(8).control(), [eig[0]] + list(phi))

with this:
for i in range(size_eig):
    qc.append(U.power(2**i).control(), [eig[i]] + list(phi))


Notice how now qubit $\text{eig}_0$ controls $U^1$ and $\text{eig}_3$ controls $U^8$.
Running a simulation for this circuit gives the correct result, which is: {'1010': 1024}

Problem solved. Thank you.
